# Toggle switch to pass unchecked value

Tags: html, forms

I'm using a checkbox to create a toggle switch as shown in this [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

The switch lives in a form where questions can be added dynamically. On submission the form posts as array of each answer back to the page to be processed however as the off switch doesn't pass a value back to the form the answers get out of sync with the answers for the other text fields. Is there any way to set a value for the off switch, i.e. when a check box is left unchecked?

I've tried to use the following to set my off checkboxes to off however it just seems to animate all the switches to on on form submission, anyone any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    var b = $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)");
    $(b).each(function () {
        $(this).val(0); //Set whatever value you need for 'not checked'
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    });
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use Javascript to set a value for each checkbox "switch" in one of two ways:

Option 1: in the html of the switch elements/checkboxes, set the value attribute to zero by default.  Then add a javascript click handler for the toggle to check its current value and toggle to the opposite state/value.

Option 2: add Javascript to the form's submit handler (on submit) that checks for any switch elements which have no values and set them to zero before processing form.

Either way should pass a value at all times, and your form should be able to keep track of all input states.

Comment: Great, I think I'm going to try to set all the value that are not checked to 0 on form submission. I've tried to do this with the javascript code outlined in the edit however this seems to animate all my off checkboxes to on when I submit the form. Not quite sure what's going wrong here, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet did the trick, as Anson suggested this finds all the checkboxes and sets them to either on or off on form submission:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').each( function () {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        if( checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            checkbox.attr('value','1');
        } else {
            checkbox.after().append(checkbox.clone().attr({type:'hidden', value:0}));
            checkbox.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    })
});
```